# "stat failed" problems on NFS sharing

Tags: php, linux, nfs, stat

On production servers we have a mount point with NFS:

```
192.168.160.5:/var/www on /var/www type nfs (rw,sync,noatime,intr,soft,timeo=30,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr,soft,timeo=30,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,addr=192.168.160.5)
```

We have 2 machines that are mounted this way, but lately we are experiencing weird problems. For example, the following script:

```
clearstatcache();
if ( !file_exists($file_path) ) {
    return false;
}
//calc time
$mtime = filemtime($file_path);
```

Gives error:

> filemtime() [function.filemtime]: **stat failed for**
>   /var/www/XXX/954340789.2319_.html
>   in
>   /var/www/XXX.module
>   on line 66.

I can't reproduce this error whenever I want, meaning it occurs randomly.

Any suggestion how to try to deal with the problem?

More information:

- All servers are Debian 6.0.5 (Squeeze)
- kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64
- PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze9

Comment: Same version of the same distro on both ends?  Which distro(s)?

Comment: yes, question updated. all servers are squeeze 6.0.5

Comment: 64-bit?  What PHP version?  I don't remember if Squeeze shipped with 5.3 or 5.2.  See also [PHP bug #48099](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48099) and [#45040](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45040)

Comment: more info added. I'm looking into this bug, but my problem occurs randomly and I can't always reproduce it :(

Comment: Okay.  Unfortunately outside of breaking out the tracing tools as suggested in the bugs, I have no further help for you...

Comment: :)
Thanks for trying to help anyway. I can't manage to reproduce the problem therefore I can't run strace (at least not on production servers).

Comment: @Charles: I think I've figure out the problem. Look at the answer.

Comment: Oh duh.  Logs.  Of course.

Comment: I also got this problem when the file is > 2G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course... 
Linux kernel log can give you lot of information... :O

```
cat /var/log/messages
Jan 29 08:50:16 XXX kernel: : [21599205.989424] nfs: server 192.168.160.53 not responding, timed out
Jan 29 08:50:16 XXX kernel: : [21599206.093387] nfs: server 192.168.160.53 not responding, timed out
Jan 29 08:50:17 XXX kernel: : [21599206.461316] nfs: server 192.168.160.53 not responding, timed out
```

I'll not delete this question, it might help someone else....